# Никто не забыт и ничто не забыто

Tags: грамотная-речь

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в предложении нет запятой: Никто не забыт и ничто не забыто. Я считала, что здесь две основы, предложение сложносочиненное и нужна запятая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никто не забыт и ничто не забыто. С точки зрения формальной грамматики, похоже на два двусоставных предложения с сочинительной связью.

Но семантика у этих предложений какая-то смутная.  Утверждается отсутствие субъекта действия или состояния, а это уже тема безличных предложений (отрицательно-бытийных).

А в этом случае их можно считать однородными и запятую не ставить - пауза явно отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы в этом предложении был общий для двух частей предложения второстепенный член, например дополнение, тогда запятая не ставилась бы. Ср.: ***Нами никто не забыт и ничто не забыто.***

Но в отсутствие общего элемента запятая нужна. ***Никто не забыт, и ничто не забыто.***

Comment: Еще этот текст встречается без союза И, тогда тоже никаких проблем, просто ставится запятая.

Answer (score 0):

> Я считала, что здесь две основы, предложение сложносочиненное и нужна
> запятая.

**Грамота.ру** с Вами согласна. См.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

===========================================

**P.S.**

Но я бы запятую не поставил.

Comment: Я уже читала этот ответ справочной службы. А почему Вы не поставите запятую? Объясните.

Comment: Просто не вижу надобности в этой запятой. Пытался когда-то при обсуждении этого ответа Справки сослаться на восклицательную интонацию в разбираемом предложении... См. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4493&p=236671&hilit=273571#p236671